# Caliburn.Micro Bootstrapper muted - DisplayRootView is gone

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I upgraded Caliburn.micro and had a breaking change from 1.0 to 1.1 - method *DisplayRootView* is gone from Bootstrapper. While in a minor example this did not seem to be an issue, I have a project that remains silent. No "GetInstance" is called, no window appearing, ViewModel is not instantiated.

I am stumped.

What kind of magic am I missing this time round?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From changset [1c1b60d46f3e](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/1c1b60d46f3e):

> Breaking change in the Bootstrapper. Removed DisplayRootView. Developers wishing to customize this should just override OnStartup. Added a Helper method to the Bootstrapper called DisplayRootViewFor which is now used by Bootstrapper in it's OnStartup override. This method is available in the standard bootstrapper for developers who need custom logic for startup, but don't wish to copy/paste the root view initialization code.

Changesets with "breaking changes" between 1.0 RTW and 1.1 RTW, latest first:

- [551d026dde5a](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/551d026dde5a)
- [1c1b60d46f3e](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/1c1b60d46f3e)
- [f749bccbde2e](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/f749bccbde2e)
- [871bd95de43f](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/871bd95de43f)
- [aaccdf5aadd3](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/aaccdf5aadd3)

Comment: D'oh! Overrode OnStartup without calling its base. That's Holiday for you, you come back dumber. Thanks!